# Compiling a list using INDEX but need to skip certain rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm compiling a list based on the first answers recieved between row N and AF.

I'm using these two formulas:
=INDEX(N2:O2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(N2:O2),0))
and
=INDEX(R2:AF2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(R2:AF2),0))

Is there a way to combine them whilst not searching in rows P & Q?

These are generated from a Form response so can't just be switched around.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know your layouts, data, data types. We don't have a big picture on your end goal. I can *guess* that there is a simpler way to do what you're doing all around. But without any contextual data and a place to write and test formulas using that data, the volunteer contributors here are left to guess at a lot. The most efficient means of getting *the best* solution is to share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), and to manually enter the results you expect (at least a few cells' worth, if applicable).

Comment: Here's a copy of the Spreadsheet with altered data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113Ki83-3km4itqMLksXTERpov-KwdA3YNjr7TGkyq5M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did the amended solution provided by player0 below work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see any changes.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX({N2:O2, R2:AF2}, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK({N2:O2, R2:AF2}), 0))
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this and only works on certain rows - this is a version of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113Ki83-3km4itqMLksXTERpov-KwdA3YNjr7TGkyq5M/edit?usp=sharing - You can see in the last column that I've used the above formula as well as other formulas I tested.

Comment: @MatthewHarrison fixed. try now

Comment: Which column did you do this in? I can't see any changes XD

Answer (score 0):

If Sheet1 is an intake sheet of form results, you should not add any data, formulas or even formatting to that sheet. It virtually always causes issues. A form intake sheet should be left exactly as it is. A *new* sheet can then be used to bring over the results of the form intake sheet as you want to see them.

However, since you didn't specify any of that, I will supply a formula written to work in the same sheet as your posted example and in-sheet examples.

Clear an entire column and place the following in the top cell of that column:

`=ArrayFormula({"Attendee Name"; IF(E2:E="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(IF(N2:AK="",,N2:AK&"~"),N1:AK1=N1)),,COLUMNS(N1:AK1)))),"\s*([^~]+)"),"(none listed)"))})`

This one formula will produce a header (the text of which you can change within the formula itself as you lie) and all valid results for all rows.

The inner `IF` will append a tilde (`~`) to any non-null entries in the range N2:AK.

`FILTER` will keep only those columns in this range where the header is the same as the header in N1 (i.e., "Attendee Name").

`TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(     ),,COLUMNS( )))` is colloquially called a "Query smash." It will form one cell from all horizontal results per row.

`TRIM` will cut any preliminary spaces and form a true string.

`REGEXEXTRACT` will pull the from the first non-space character up to but not including the first tilde (from those appended in the first step)—in other words, the first full valid entry from any column.

`IFERROR` will return a message if there is an error, with the likely error being that there were *no valid entries* for "Attendee name" in any column.

The outer `IF` will leave the cell blank if the no training event exists in E2:E.

`{ }` forms a virtual array that places the header over all other results.

`ArrayFormula( )` signifies that multiple results will be processed at once.

Because this is an array formula that is being "asked" to process every row, you cannot manually type into any cell of this results column. If you do, you will "break the array"; everything except what you just typed will disappear, leaving only an error in the formula cell. If you need to add or change a name, you need to do that in the raw results range (e.g., manually type a name or a new name in Col N), which will then turn up in the formula output range.

Comment: This almost works for me but is picking up the columns I want to skip - I think it's picking up P which I don't want it to read. This is really helpful though!

Comment: It's not possible that the formula is picking up any columns that don't have the same header as N1. I tested the formula in a copy of your shared sample spreadsheet, and it worked as expected. If you are attempting to apply the formula to some spreadsheet that is not the one you shared via link above, then you've made changes to the unshared spreadsheet that are not the same as the one you shared. Feel free to share an updated link below.